# Why $R(X,Y)$ is a rotation and why can we think of $R(X,Y)$ depending on $X\wedge Y$

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, curvature

$R$ denotes the Riemann curvature operator $R(X,Y)Z:=\nabla_{X}(\nabla_{Y}Z)-\nabla_{Y}(\nabla_{X}Z)-\nabla_{[X,Y]}Z$

I am trying to understand why $\langle R(X,Y)Z,W\rangle=-\langle R(X,Y)W,Z\rangle$ is equivalent to saying $R(X,Y)$ is a rotation? My guess is that it somehow implies that $R(X,Y)$ is somehow an orthogonal map.

Regarding the second question in the title there is unfortunately little I can write since there is not much about it in the lecture notes.

Comment: Perhaps you mean an infinitesimal rotation.

Comment: Where did you found that "this is equivalent to saying that $R(X,Y)$ is a rotation"? What lecture notes are you refering to?

Comment: Yes I meant infinitesimal. However I am not sure what it exactly means. Here is the link https://www3.math.tu-berlin.de/geometrie/Lehre/WS19/DGII/

Comment: It is on page 35.

Comment: So your question could be rephrased as _how skew symmetric matrices correspond to infinitesimal rotations_?

Comment: I suppose. As I said I am not familiar with infinitisimal rotations. A quick google search showed that it is something that is often used in mechanics. Are there any books that cover this topic?

Comment: You should seach in your favourite web browser "Lie algebra of $SO(n)$" or anything related.

Comment: A map $R: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is a rotation about the origin if and only if there is a matrix $M$ such that $R(v) = Mv$ and $M^tM = I.$ If $M(t)$ is a $1$-pararameter family of rotations such that $M(0) = I$, then $M'(0)$ is an infinitesimal rotation. Differentiating the equation above, $$0 = M'(0)^tM(0) + M(0)^tM'(0) = M'(0)^t + M'(0).$$ Conversely, given any skew-symmetric matrix $\dot{M}$, there is a $1$-parameter family of rotatations $M(t)$ such that $M(0) = I$ and $M'(0) = \dot{M}$.

Comment: @Deane I am afraid I still have some questions. Is the definition of inf. rotation $R=I+\epsilon X$? I see how the skew-symmetry follows from differentiating $M^{t}M=I$. Why is $M'(0)=I+\epsilon X$ for some $\epsilon,X$.? Does it follow from a Taylor exspansion? Is there a dot above the last M?

Comment: No. If $X$ is skew-symmetric, $I + \epsilon X$ is *not* a rotation. What is true is that there exists a $1$-parameter family of rotations, $R(t)$ such that $R(0) = I$ and $R'(0) = X$. This means that for $\epsilon$ small, $R(\epsilon) = I + \epsilon X + \epsilon^2\dots$. $\dot{M}$ is meant to represent any skew-symmetric matrix. It's what you call $X$ in your latest comment.

Comment: Okay, but I am still not sure what the definition of an inf. rotation is. Is the 1-paramter family $R(t)=e^{tX}$?